# Jersey 1.x to 2.x: simple web.xml change, failing miserably

Tags: java, maven, jersey, web.xml, jersey-2.0

Okay, I literally don't know how much simpler I can make this test case.  I have the most minimal code in all respects, and yet it works in Jersey 1.x and fails with the Glassfish version.  Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

By "failing" and "not working", I mean that, when I stand it up in a Tomcat container and try to hit it in a browser, the first version is successful, but the second one fails.

```java
@Path("/service")
public class MyService {

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "Yay!";
    }

}
```

... working web.xml with Jersey 1.x ...

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.service.package</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

... just replace two strings for Glassfish, and the whole thing breaks.

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.service.package</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

---

pom.xml for Jersey 1.x

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.3</version>
</dependency>
```

... and for 2.x ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a bit more detail about exactly what is happening. "The whole thing breaks" is not very descriptive.

Comment: @Rob Yeah, sorry.  I meant it in the simplest way: with the first version, I can hit it in a browser (localhost:8080/project/rest/service/test), and with the second version I can't.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Post the dependency switch that causes this

Comment: Try and use the dependency [from this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27799899/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet Wow, that worked!  Thank you so much!  I'm a little worried that when I go to call other services via `Client` that it won't work (since it's not the `jersey-server` artifact), but this at least gets me going.

Comment: If you post as an answer, I'll accept.  Alternatively, we can close as a duplicate or I can delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below dependency should pull in all the required dependencies you need to get up and running.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>
```