# Issues in JAXRS Rest service using jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Deployed a demo Rest Service on tomcat 7 using jersey JAXRS API . Developed a resource class

```
@Path("/supportdata")
public class SupportDataService {
    public SupportDataService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String getSupportData(){
        String xmlSupport=null;

        xmlSupport="<SupportData><Support><key>path1</key><value>value1</value></Support><Support><key>path2</key><value>value2</value></Support></SupportData>";

        return xmlSupport;
    }
}
```

Sub class of Application

```
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    public RestApplication() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Set<Class<?>> s=new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(SupportDataService.class);
        return s;
    }
}
 Web.xml contains

<web-app>
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.jaxrs.RestApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.jaxrs.RestApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Included javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar from jersey in the project. Deployed it on defaultport of tomcat 7 and calling the url  on local host port 8080 and url
```

/RestService/resources/supportdata

getting a 404 error of resource not available.

Comment: servlet class seems missing from web.xml?

Comment: And have you included also Jersey in your war or just `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar`?

Answer (score 1):

### Given...

1. `RestApplication` is in the `com.jaxrs` package
2. You have the required dependencies **<sup>[1]</sup>**
3. No other unknown issues related to something you're not showing us

### All you need to do to get this to work...

is change

```
 <url-pattern>/resources</url-pattern>
```

to

```
 <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
```

The resource should be accessible via `http://localhost:8080/yourapp/resources/supportdata`

Tested this and it works fine. `/resources` is limiting the url pattern to strictly `/resources`. When you add the `/*` you are saying *anything* with the `/resources` prefix.

---

**[1]** :

Using Maven, this is the only dependency I used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Not using Maven (ahhhh, whyyy?):

I suggest you download the [RI Bundle from here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) and include all the jars into your project.

---

And just for others scratching their head about the OP's configuration, this is from the JAX-RS spec:

> If an `Application` subclass is present:
>
> - If there is already a servlet that handles this application. That is, a servlet that has an initialization parameter named
>
>   `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`
>
>   whose value is the fully qualified name of the Application subclass, then no additional configuration steps are required by the JAX-RS implementation.
> - If no servlet handles this application, JAX-RS implementations are REQUIRED to dynamically add a servlet whose fully qualified name must be that of the Application subclass. If the `Application` subclass is annotated with `@ApplicationPath`, implementations are REQUIRED to use the value of this annotation appended with `"/*"` to define a mapping for the added server. Otherwise, the application MUST be packaged with a `web.xml` that specifies a servlet mapping. For example, if `org.example.MyApplication` is the name of the Application subclass, a sample `web.xml` would be:

```
1   <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
2                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
3                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
4                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
5       <servlet>
6            <servlet-name>org.example.MyApplication</servlet-name>
7       </servlet>
8       <servlet-mapping>
9            <servlet-name>org.example.MyApplication</servlet-name>
10           <url-pattern>/myresources/*</url-pattern>
11      </servlet-mapping>
12  </web-app>
```

Comment: I am getting this error         javax.servlet.ServletException: No servlet class has been specified for servlet com.jaxrs.RestApplication

Comment: Please see the second "Given". Either use the Maven Dependency, or download and add _all the jars_ from that download bundle. I have tested both ways, with pretty much your exact code

Comment: If we are specifying srevlet name as com.jaxrs.RestApplication how will this identify the name of the servlet class as javax.ws.rs.core.Application is not a servlet and com.jaxrs.RestApplication is a subclass of Application.

Comment: Read the last bullet point in the specification. You could use the Jersey `ServletContainer` but that is not the problem. I've already tested with the name of the class, with no servlet specified, and it works fine.